# Eye distance relative to shoulder

Tags: opencv, image-processing, face-detection, object-detection

I am looking for a method to determine the distance between the eyes and top of the shoulder of a person in an image. At first I tried to use haar cascade in opencv to detect the eye position, which worked fine. However, I couldn't find any way to detect the shoulders. I think that it will be a lot of work to come up with my own training sets for my own shoulder detection model, so I am wondering if there is any easier way to do this.

[image: example]

Comment: Do you have any sample images? I ask because if you want a simple solution, there must be a way to constrain the problem. For eg: images of ppl against a light background. If you have a natural background, the problem is going to be harder

Comment: @ShawnMathew There isn't really any consistent background for what I am trying to use it for. I hope there is still some way to do it with a natural background.

Comment: you did not specify any accuracy... what's the variance of that distance? I have my doubts that this even makes sense unless you have a special imaging setup. where is the shoulder anyway?

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford enough computing power, [OpenPose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) is a good solution. A simpler approach is described [here](http://media.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/~ahz/papers/Human%20Head%20Shoulder%20Segmentation.v.1.1.pdf), I have tried it and it works ok.

You can get a rough estimate of the shoulder width given the eye location using the following rules (used by artists):
Width of the head is twice the distance between the eyes.
Eyes are located halfway between the top of the head and the tip of the chin
[This diagram](http://www.realcolorwheel.com/final.htg/2ani.gif) can help you to estimate the distance between the chin tip and the shoulders.